# Azure Devops Environments - Export work items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We've been using environments for a while now for our dev and test instances. I like being able to go to the environment and seeing the commits and work items associated with the particular build/release but can't find a way to export them. Does anyone know of a way to export the workitems?

[image]

Using environments you also loose the ability to see which build/release a ticket went out in or have I missed something?

[image: deployment]

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second question, kind of, have the same answer.

In short, you don't want to be using **Environments** to view which work items are associated with a release.

Azure DevOps has a built-in mechanism to view work items directly within the **Release** or **Pipelines** page (Depending on whether you're using classic or YAML).

Here is a great guide published by Microsoft regarding how work pipeline-based work item linking works, as well as how to retrieve work items associated with a release:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-retrieve-all-work-items-associated-with-a-release-pipeline-using-azure-devops-api/

*Update:*

Specifically regarding how to view linked work items in **Pipelines**. You'll want to look under "Related":

[image: Related Work Items - Pipelines]

Clicking on "x work items" will show you the full list of work items:

[image: Related Work Items List - Pipelines]

Comment: I read that blog before posting the question.  We using deployment jobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops and not releases which your linked blog post mentions